# How to itemize as [1], [2] in LaTeX?

Tags: itemize

I want to itemize as
[1] sentences
[2] sentences....

But if I type

```
\begin{description} \itemsep -2pt % Reduce space between items
\item[[1]] sentences
\end{description}
```

in latex, it appears

> [1 ] sentences

And if I type

```
\begin{description} \itemsep -2pt % Reduce space between items
\item[$[1]$] sentences
\end{description}
```

in latex, it gives me error.

How can I do it?

Comment: Rather then `description`, are you looking for `itemize` or `enumerate`? You can customize those environments using package `enumitem`.

Comment: Also consider package `paralist` which adds the possibility of having in-line enumeration.

Comment: are the items going to be enumerated consecutively, or could there be gaps?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  It is usually best to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating which documentclass you are using.

Comment: @JPi Actually, `enumitem` has in-line lists, too.

Answer (score 7):

Using `description` is problematic. Why not `enumerate` or `itemize`? But, in any case, you should put `[1]` in a group, e.g., `\item[{[1]}]`. If LaTeX in this context looks for a closing `]`, it simply closes all from beginning `[`. Hence from `\item[[1]]` you have `[1` and the next `]` is not an argument, but the beginning of text following it.

Answer (score 4):

`\usepackage{enumitem}` and in the body of your document:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}, noitemsep]
\item First item
\item Second item
................
\end{enumerate}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Hmm, did you test it? I see at least two problems.

Comment: To be frank, I didn't, as there was no minimal example. Now that you point it (thanks!), I can see one (double ?) problem.  I've corrected it. Is there anything else?

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paralist, blindtext}

\begin{document}

Let us start. And 
\begin{inparaenum}[(1)]
  \item whatever goes below
  \item and up again
\end{inparaenum}
will be treated as nonsense that it is...
\end{document}
```

But I'm failing to have the items numbered [1].

Comment: Quote the braces: `\begin{inparaenum}[{[}1{]}]`